# Lucene not indexing String field with value "this"

Tags: lucene

I am adding the document to lucene index as follows:

```
Document doc = new Document();
String stringObj = (String)field.get(obj);
doc.add(new TextField(fieldName, stringObj.toLowerCase(), org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store.YES));
indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
```

I am doing a wild card search as follows:

```
searchTerm = "*" + searchTerm + "*";
term = new Term(field, sTerm.toLowerCase());
Query query = new WildcardQuery(term);
TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
indexSearcher.search(query, collector);
if(collector.getTotalHits() > 0){
    TopDocs hits = indexSearcher.search(query, collector.getTotalHits());
}
```

When I have a string with a "this" value, it is not getting added to the index, hence i do not get the result on searching by "this". I am using a StandardAnalyzer.

Comment: "this" is a stop word.

Answer (score 1):

Common terms of English language like prepositions, pronouns etc are marked as stop words and omitted before indexing. You can define a custom analyzer or custom stop word list for your analyzer. That way you will be able to omit words that you don't want to be indexed and keep the stop words that you need.